# node.js cannot parse ISOString date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

We store every date data in ISO format using new Date().toISOString().

I tried to convert this ISO formatted date into Date object in node.js but I get Invalid Date response.

date string is `isoDate = 2014-07-09T14:00:00.000Z`
and I did `console.log` on `Date.parse(isoDate);` and `new Date(isoDate);`
but each returns `NaN` and `Invalid Date`.

I checked if the date string contains any invisible wrong character but they are fine and can be converted on browser console.

does this mean I need to convert the string manually and create Date object with parsed string?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Works just fine here... Are you sure isoDate is a string? (and not - for example - a Buffer)

Comment: Yes just did typeof check it says string. could this be version specific? we are using 0.10.29 at the moment.

Comment: I'm using the same version. In any case, it should work in any version of node...

Comment: Well this is strange, to make sure I'm using correct string I just tried creating new ISO String on node.js and creating Date object from the string but it returns Invalid Date.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().toISOString())` works perfectly fine for me

Comment: What happens when you do `new Date(Date.parse('2014-07-09T14:00:00.000Z'))` ?

Comment: It depends on the javascript version. My have experiences with a embedded javascript version below 1.8.5 (1.8.0) and have the same problem. You need 1.8.5 or greate to parse ISO String Dates. Also the parse method is missing in obsolete versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library. It has a lot of functionality to work with dates and can easily be used both on client and server side. Calling `moment("2014-07-09T14:00:00.000Z").toDate()` would convert your string to a Date JavaScript Object, using this library.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer just in case somebody experience this like I did.

What happened to me is I thought I was sending an ISOString from the browser

```
{
  startDate: date.startDate
}
```

which in fact I was sending a moment instance as parameter

When I checked in the network inspector I found out that the data being sent is in ISO format - yes, but it is enclosed in double quote ""

```
{
  startDate: "2016-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"
}
```

it should not be enclosed in double qoutes and should look like this

```
{
  startDate: 2016-12-31T16:00:00.000Z
}
```

what worked for me is to parse the moment to iso string

```
{
  startDate: date.startDate.toISOString()
}
```